# Averaging successive pairs of values in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to take the average of successive pairs of ints in a 2d array.

e.g. if the starting array looks like this:

```
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
];
```

The resulting array should look like:

```
[
  [1.5, 3.5, 5.5],
  [15, 35, 55]
]
```

My method is to loop through each array in turn, using %2 to select every other value, add them together and then push to a new 2d array.

Can anyone guide why the actual result is:

```
[
  [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 15, 35, 55],
  [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 15, 35, 55]
]
```

Here is my code:

```
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
];

//create the same number of empty arrays as there are arrays in data.
var averagedCols = new Array(data.length).fill([]);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    if (j%2 === 0) {
      var average = (data[i][j] + data[i][j+1])/2;
      averagedCols[i].push(average);
    } 
  }
}
console.log(averagedCols);
```

https://jsbin.com/rogemonave/edit?js,console

Note: jsbin also prints `[circular object Array]` when I try to print the whole resulting array, but a quick google seems to say this is a problem with jsbin not my code as this is not happening on my computer. Could still be an issue with my code though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that when you do `.fill([])`, you're filling with *multiple references of the same empty array* - there's only one empty array in memory, which each index of `averagedCols` refers to. You can fix this by explicitly creating the array on each iteration with `Array.from`:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
];

//create the same number of empty arrays as there are arrays in data.
var averagedCols = Array.from(
  { length: data.length },
  () => []
);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    if (j%2 === 0) {
      var average = (data[i][j] + data[i][j+1])/2;
      averagedCols[i].push(average);
    } 
  }
}
console.log(averagedCols);
```

Best to only use `.fill` when filling an array with *primitives* - for non-primitives (objects, arrays, and functions), use `Array.from` instead.

The logic will probably be easier if you first chunk the array items into pairs, eg `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` to `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]`. Then, all you need is a simple `.map` to average each pair:

```js
function toPairs(arr) {
  const pairs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
    pairs.push(arr.slice(i, i + 2));
  }
  return pairs;
}

const input = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
];
const output = input
  .map(toPairs)
  .map(arrayOfPairs => arrayOfPairs.map(pair => (pair[0] + pair[1]) / 2));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the argument that is passed to the `fill()` function is a value, so all entries in your `averagedCols` array will refer to the same empty array instance that you pass in using `fill([])`.

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a map function to initialize your result array:

```
var averagedCols = Array.from(data, _ => []);
```

---

Complete snippet:

```js
var data = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
];

var averagedCols = Array.from(data, _ => []);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    if (j%2 === 0) {
      var average = (data[i][j] + data[i][j+1])/2;
      averagedCols[i].push(average);
    } 
  }
}
console.log(averagedCols);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a fancy single function, I think it would be easier to make a simple function that takes the average for a single array. Then map it over the array of arrays:

```js
let n =[
   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
   [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
];
function averageByTwo(arr){
    // give an array with even number of numbers take the average of pairs
    // assumes even number, adjust if not safe assumption
    return Array.from({length: arr.length/2}, (_, i) => (arr[i * 2] + arr[i *2+1]) /2)
}

// now you can map it over any number of arrays
let averages = n.map(arr => averageByTwo(arr))
console.log(averages)
```

Comment: I accepted @CertainPerformance answer as it provided more information as to why my code wasn't working as expected, however I have used your code in my project as the logic seems clearer to me.

Comment: No need to explain @jopfre — it was a good answer. Glad you got it working.